# Passing a 2d array of vector to a class constructor

Tags: c++

In my code, I have some data stored in an 2d array of vector and I'd like to use it in another class to process the data but I can't find a way to do that.

Here is a sample of what I tried :

```
vector<IndividualData> vecArray[5][5]; // The one I want to pass to the class

MyClass::MyClass(vector<IndividualData> data[][5], ...):_data(data)
```

Is there a good way to do that?

I also tried with the std::array but I can't make it work :

```
array<array<vector<IndividualData>, 5>, 5> testVec; // Ther one I want to pass to the class

MyClass::MyClass(array<array<vector<IndividualData>, 5>, 5>& data, ...): _data(data)
```

When I want to use it in the class, I get the following error :

> Type 'array<array<vector, 5>, 5>' does not provide a subscript operator

With

```
printf("%d\r\n", _data[0][0][0].param);
```

and

```
array<array<vector<IndividualData>, 5>, 5>& _data;
```

Thank's in advance for your replies

Comment: Use `std::array` or another vector. Passing raw arrays by value is nearly impossible  and never safe because they will happily decay to pointers, e.g. `_data(data)` would not do what you think if it would compile..

Comment: Use `std::array` instead of c-style arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```cpp
using My2DArrayOfVec = std::array<std::array<std::vector<IndividualData>, 5>, 5>;

class MyClass
{
   My2DArrayOfVec _data;
public:
   MyClass(My2DArrayOfVec const& data, ...) : _data(data) {}
   void useIt() const { printf("%d\r\n", _data[0][0][0].param); }
};
```

By having an alias, I always use the same types, `My2DArrayOfVec`, inside and outside of my class even when I'm experimenting.

Comment: Thank's for you reply, I was not so far away from the solution but I forgot to include the <array> that's why I still had some errors.